# How can I automatically format a list of assignments in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio

In my code, I have many object creations and assignments like this:

```
val exampleEntity = ExampleEntity (
            element1= value1,
            elementbig1 =value1,
            elementsmall1 = value1,
            elementcenter= value1,
            elementRight = value1,
            elementbetween1 = value1,

            elementLeft =value1,



           elementFirst = value1,

            elementSecond = value1,
)
```

I would like to know a way, in Android Studio, to format it so that it looks like this:

```
val exampleEntity = ExampleEntity (
    element1        = value1,
    elementbig1     = value1,
    elementsmall1   = value1,
    elementcenter   = value1,
    elementRight    = value1,
    elementbetween1 = value1,
    elementLeft     = value1,
    elementFirst    = value1,
    elementSecond   = value1,
)
```

Adding spaces, befores and after of the equal sign and deleting empty lines.

I have tried different options with the Code Style, in the options that come in this window:

File-> Settings-> Editor-> Code Style-> Kotlin

but I have not achieved the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL + ALT + L` format code for `Windows`.
`Command + Alt + L` for `OS X`.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + L  doesn't work for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I did not see any thing which can remove line space. Maybe you need plugin I know a plugin that will help you codeGlance. just open android studio setting find plugins then select market tab then search this pluging.
Note this plugin will style your code and cannot remove space